# How can I launch a Samsung home screen shortcut via Tasker?

Tags: android, android-intent, tasker, android-shortcut

My security company's mobile app (CPI inTouch) allows me to create "scenes" which trigger multiple actions at the same time with a press of one button (e.g. disarming the alarm and unlocking the smart lock on my door). I've also added shortcuts to each of the scenes on my home screen (on my Samsung Galaxy Note9, if that's relevant) so I can launch a scene via the shortcut without having to go into the app itself.

However, having just purchased Tasker, **I'd like to trigger the shortcut** (or the activity in the app itself) programmatically **in a Tasker profile** or some other automation app. I've tried plenty of apps that allow you to trigger a shortcut based on an event, but none have these particular shortcuts in the list of available ones. I read that I should be able to use a Send Intent task in Tasker to do this, but I don't know what the intent string would be or where to find it.

In case you can suggest a different way to achieve this, the main use case so far is to have my alarm system automatically disarmed when my phone's morning alarm goes off.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check would be...

create new task to Launch App,
find your CPI app and if it has a "+" in top right corner of app icon you can long press it to reveal a list of activities.

if your app does not offer those options...

The Tasker dev also has a group of plugins under the AutoApps group, there is one called AutoShortcut that launches shortcuts.

edit: there are apps such as APK Analyzer that can show you the activities and services inside an app and whether or not they can receive intents from external apps.